# Prove that $\det($Hilbert Matrix minus $\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}$ in the top left$)=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, integration, polynomials, determinant

If $f$ is a polynomial of degree $n$ such that
$\int_0^1 f(x)x^kdx=0$ for all $k=1,2,\dots,n$, then $\int_0^1 f^2(x)dx=(n+1)^2\left(\int_0^1 f(x)dx\right)^2.$

This implies that $\begin{vmatrix}
1-\frac{1}{(n+1)^2}& \frac{1}{2}& \frac{1}{3} & \cdots & \frac{1}{n+1} \\
\frac{1}{2}& \frac{1}{3} & \frac{1}{4}& \cdots & \frac{1}{n+2} \\
\frac{1}{3}& \frac{1}{4}& \frac{1}{5} & \cdots & \frac{1}{n+3}\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots  \\
\frac{1}{n+1}& \frac{1}{n+2}& \frac{1}{n+3}& \cdots & \frac{1}{2n+1}\\
\end{vmatrix}=0.$

Does it have a more direct algebraic proof?

Comment: If not for the $\dfrac{1}{\left(n+1\right)^2}$ in the northwestern corner, this would be a Cauchy matrix, with a well-known determinant (I think it's called a Hilbert matrix). Now the $\dfrac{1}{\left(n+1\right)^2}$ adds a certain minor to its determinant, but that minor is itself the determinant of a Cauchy matrix, so it can too be computed.

Comment: Excellent! Now I can prove it simply. Thanks.